# How to structure a multi-module project with Python and JVM-based stack

Tags: python, git, intellij-idea, virtualenv, pipenv

We are defining a structure for a new project having multiple modules which may include Python and JVM-based sub-projects. Before having Python in the stack, we used Gradle which took care of almost all our configurations. Now we want to have Python in the stack in multiple different modules.

What are the recommendations to manage/structure such projects? How could these recommendations change knowing that all developers are using `IntelliJ IDEA`?

What do we have currently:

- For each `Java`/`scala` module: a `Gradle`-based module where all our dependencies are automatically taken care of when importing the project and/or refreshing the Gradle porject.
- For each `Python` module: a `requirements.txt` file having all the required packages for this module. The developer is asked to manually create a Python virtual environment and set it as the `Module SDK` in IntelliJ IDEA (This is our main pain point, we want to automate this somehow).

What do we need to know exactly:

- What to push to our git repository so that we are as close as possible to the zero-configuration structure for whoever clone/pull from the repository?
- Using a Python virtual environment per Python module, how to manage the packages and the environments themselves?
- Is it a good idea to start directly with [Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) although it is still not supported in IntelliJ IDEA, although [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26492) looks promising?
- How to manage inter-module Python dependencies? Should we use any Python distributions utils?